# Volume of a solid in the shaded region $y=\frac {2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, x=(-1,1)$, rotated about the $x$ axis

Tags: integration, trigonometry

[image]

> Find the exact volume of the solid formed when the shaded region $y=\dfrac {2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, x=(-1,1)$ is rotated completely about the $x$ axis.

This is the question with the diagram I tried integraing it and butting the $1$ at top and $-1$ at bottom but it became $3.53$ which is wrong then I just filled in the $x$ and that became $0$ which is wrong I am on the chapter of integration of $1/(x^2+a^2)$ but I honestly don't know how to solve it as the root is over the whole of $x^2+1$ and I don't know how to solve it and what they want I know the answer is $2π^2$ but don't know how to get to it any help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: If the region is being revolved around the $ \ x- $ axis, you will want to use the "disk method", integrating from $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ to $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ and doubling the result since the region has symmetry about the $ \ y-$ axis.  You don't need to solve for any roots of the function.

Comment: @boojum ow i have never heard of this method how to you do this? i mean I tried now and got 3.52. could you please help me.

Comment: Since the region is being revolved around the $ \ x-$ axis, any vertical slice through the resulting volume is a disk with area $ \ \pi \ [ \ f(x) \ ]^2 \ $ and a "thickness" $ \ dx \ $ , The volume integral will be $$  \ \int_{-1}^1 \ \pi \  \left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)^2 \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ 2 \pi \ \int_0^1 \ \frac{4}{x^2+1} \ \ dx \ \ . $$  That integrand ought to look like something you know an anti-derivative for.  You haven't covered this in integration yet?

Comment: @boojum owww i seee and you made it 2 because you made it 1-0 and then you doubled it. I have never seen this method thank you very much!

Comment: You should probably be learning about it and the "shell method" pretty soon then, if you are being set problems about solids of revolution.  I'm glad this helped.